# Анимация в Android Canvas для minSdkVersion="8"

Tags: java, android, анимация, animate

В моей словесной игре типа "Эрудита" для Android отсутствует анимация -

Например, при выборе в меню "Вернуть буквы" фишки просто удаляются с игрового поля и потом (вдруг!) показываются внизу экрана.

Тоже самое с "Помешать буквы" - фишки просто рисуются на новых позициях внизу экрана:

[image: android app screenshot]

Конечно, это выглядит не очень наглядно и мне хотелось бы добавить простые анимации для буквенных фишек - но при этом не терять совместимость с Android 2.2 - поэтому нельзя например использовать [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html).

Кроме того, мне кажется, что можно обойтись без `Runnable` и создания дополнительных thread-ов - потому что я уже успешно анимирую flinging игрового поля (когда пользователь скроллит его энергичным движением пальца) в главном thread при помощи [ScrollerCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ScrollerCompat.html).

Вот класс буквенных фишек:

```
public class Tile {
    public static int sWidth;
    public static int sHeight;

    // этот прямоугольник содержит координаты и размер фишки
    private Rect mRect = new Rect();
```

Для анимации я решил добавить в этот класс конечные координаты и флаг, что движение фишки еще не закончилось:

```
    private Point mTarget = new Point();
    public boolean moving = false;
```

И два метода для перемещения фишки - без и с анимацией:

```
    public void move(int x, int y) {
        mRect.left = x;
        mRect.top = y;
        mRect.right = x + sWidth;
        mRect.bottom = y + sHeight;
    }

    public void moveAnimated(int x, int y) {
        moving = true;
        mTarget.x = x;
        mTarget.y = y;
    }
```

Потом, в методе отрисовки моего главного custom `View` я вызываю:

```
public class GameView extends View {
    private static final int DELAY = 30;
    private ArrayList<SmallTile> mBarTiles = new ArrayList<SmallTile>();

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mGameBoard.isFlinging()) {
            postInvalidateDelayed(DELAY);
        } else {
            for (SmallTile tile: mBoardTiles) {
                if (tile.moving) {
                    postInvalidateDelayed(DELAY);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // нарисовать (с учетом scroll-а) игровое поле с фишками
        mGameBoard.draw(canvas, mBoardTiles);

        // нарисовать до 7 фишек внизу экрана - с анимацией
        for (SmallTile tile: mBarTiles) 
            tile.draw(canvas);

        // нарисовать 1 фишку которую тащит пользователь
        mDraggedTile.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Как видите наверху, если одна из фишек еще в процессе движения (и ее флаг `moving=true`), то вызывается `onDraw` еще раз через 30 миллисекунд.

То же самое для анимации игрового поля - если оно еще движется (`isFlinging()` возвращает `true`) - но это уже работает без проблем.

**Теперь собственно мой вопрос**:

В процедуре отрисовке фишки нужно учесть ее движение и выставить ее актуальные координаты:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (moving) {
        int dx = mTarget.x - mRect.left;
        int dy = mTarget.y - mRect.top;

        // ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ Я ЗАСТРЯЛ - КАКИЕ КООРДИНАТЫ ВЫСТАВИТЬ?
        move(XXX, YYY); 

        // ЕСЛИ ФИШКА ДОЛЕТЕЛА - НУЖНО ВЫСТАВИТЬ moving=false
    }

    // нарисовать background фишки - желтый прямоугольник
    canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);

    // нарисовать Bitmap с буквой и ее числовым значением
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mRect.left, mRect.top);
    Drawable d = sLetters.get(mLetter);
    d.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

К сожалению, я не знаю как правильно подсчитать координаты!

У меня есть актуальные координаты фишки: `mRect.left` и `mRect.top`

У меня есть координаты куда должна прилететь фишка: `mTarget.x` и `mTarget.y`

Пока `moving==true`, каждые 30 миллисекунд вызывается код отрисовки фишки, которому нужно дать новые координаты - но как их подсчитать?

Comment: Почему не хотите использовать например http://nineoldandroids.com/, это библиотека для совместимости анимаций вплоть до 1.0 версии Android. Там также можно использовать ValueAnimator.

Comment: Да, спасибо- я уже посмотрел на нее, но опасаюсь что она будет не совместима с будущими версиями

Comment: Будущими версиями Android? Так вы можете проверять версию и в зависимости от нее использовать либо нативный ValueAnimator, либо nineoldandroids.

Comment: Окей, хорошая идея. Но мне все-таки кажется что мою проблему можно решить без внешней библиотеки - парой строчек собственного кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тогда вам нужно выбрать время анимации, допустим 1 секунда = 1000  миллисек. Тогда поделив 1000 на 30 (fps по сути) получаем 33 - количество раз, которое мы вызовем метод `draw` для достижения цели. Получается, что наш путь `dx` и `dy` тоже нужно поделить на 33, тогда мы получим шаг, на который у нас будет сдвигаться фишка, при каждом вызове `draw`. Ну а дальше остается прибавлять этот шаг к текущим координатам и с ними вызывать метод `move`:

```
move(mRect.left + (int) (dx / 33), mRect.top + (int) (dy / 33));
```