# Подсчет шагов разных размеров - для более натуральной анимации Canvas

Tags: java, android, анимация, animate

Здесь на русском StackOverflow я получил [очень хороший совет](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433756/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-android-canvas-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-minsdkversion-8) и смог добавить анимацию фишек в буквенную игру для Android.

Когда пользователь выбирает в меню "Вернуть буквы" и буква "A" должна прилететь в позицию внизу экрана, показанную красной стрелкой:

[image: Android app]

**Нынешний алгоритм работает так:**

- Текущие координаты фишки: `mRect.top` и `mRect.left`
- Конечные координаты фишки: `mTarget.x` и `mTarget.y`
- Пока на нем есть движущиеся фишки, экран мобильного приложения рисуется заново (для этого снова и снова вызывается `postInvalidate(30)`).

Когда нужно анимированно переместить фишку, я вызываю следующий метод, который делит предстоящий путь на 8 *одинаковых* шагов:

```
public void startAnimatedMove(float x, float y) {
    mTarget.x = x;
    mTarget.y = y;
    steps = 8;
    mStepX = (mTarget.x - mRect.left) / steps;
    mStepY = (mTarget.y - mRect.top) / steps;
}
```

Каждый раз, по истечении 30 миллисекунд, вызывается метод, сдвигающий фишку в нужном направлении (причем последний шаг у меня особый - он помещает фишку точно на `mTarget.x` и `mTarget.y` - чтобы избежать ошибки округления):

```
private void nextStep() {
    if (--steps == 0)
        moveTo(mTarget.x, mTarget.y);
    else 
        moveTo(mRect.left + mStepX, mRect.top + mStepY);
}
```

Этот алгоритм работает хорошо (и дает возможность анимировать фишки прямо из главного thread-а приложения), но так как шаги `mStepX` и `mStepY` одинаковые, фишка движется неестественно.

**Вопрос:**

Как бы сделать шаги неодинаковыми? Они дожны быть большими в середине пути - и маленькими в начале и конце (см. зеленый график наверху справа). Тогда фишка будет медленно начинать и заканчивать движение - так называемый "easying in out".

То есть нужна функция (с использованием `x*x` или `Math.sin()`?) для каждой оси, которая получала бы как input номер текушего шага, а выдавала как output дистанцию в пикселях вдоль оси икс или игрек:

```
private void nextStep() {
    if (--steps == 0)
        moveTo(mTarget.x, mTarget.y);
    else 
        moveTo(mRect.left + calcStepX(steps), mRect.top + calcStepY(steps));
}
```

**Обновление:**

Нашел [интересный сайт про Easing Equations by Robert Penner](http://gizma.com/easing/), но пока не разобрался, как применить их к своему программному коду - особенно как рассчитать шаги, чтобы их сумма попала в точку назначения...

Comment: вам, наверно, что-нибудь вроде [нормального распределения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CD%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%EE%E5_%F0%E0%F1%EF%F0%E5%E4%E5%EB%E5%ED%E8%E5) подойдёт.

Comment: Google предлагает такую [эстетику анимации](http://www.google.com/design/spec/animation/authentic-motion.html) как стандарт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как расчитать шаги, чтобы их сумма попала в точку назначения

Все формулы на упомянутом сайте опираются на 4 параметра: *t, b, c, d*:

1. *t* – текущее время (или номер кадра),
2. *b* – начальное значение,
3. *c* – (конечное значение - начальное значение),
4. *d* – общая длительность анимации.

Чтобы за 8 кадров некий параметр, напр., *Y*, изменился от 162 до 288, вы в понравившуюся формулу, напр., в экспонениальный out

```
return c * ( -Math.pow( 2, -10 * t/d ) + 1 ) + b;
```

подставляете b,c вашей анимации, `d=7`, а `t=просчитываемый кадр` (0..7) и получаете на выходе значение вашего параметра для этого кадра.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (+1) , но `c` это вроде бы **(конечное значение - начальное значение)**

Comment: Окей, приспособил эти функции: https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js

Comment: @AlexanderFarber точно, я поспешил.  Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Все гораздо проще. В android'е есть класс [ValueAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html)

Пользоваться примерно так:

```
ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, height);
va.setDuration(300);
va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
        v.requestLayout();
    }
});
```

Дефолтный интерполятор вычисляет значения именно так как вы хотите, т.е. начало и конец медленно, в середине быстрее. Вы естественно можете создать свой интерполятор. А если в интерполятор передать null, то будет линейно, как в вашем примере.

ЗЫ Если надо анимировать два или больше *независимых* (т.е. когда `dx` через `dy` не посчитать) параметров можно воспользоваться [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html)

Comment: Спасибо за полезный ответ (+1) но мне не подходит, так как у меня `minSdkVersion=“8”` (забыл указать в вопросе; посмотрим, смогу ли удержать его до конца написания игры :-)

Comment: @AlexanderFarber посмотрите на http://nineoldandroids.com/ пойдет вплоть до API 1. В любом случае, вы изобретаете тот же велосипед.

Comment: NineOldAndroids использует дополнительный thread, а у меня пока получается обойтись главным thread-ом (и minSdkVersion=8).